# How to integration test api endpoints of the format 'api/:id' using mocha and supertest

Tags: express, mocha.js, supertest

I am trying to integration test an API endpoint to return a specific user data by attaching the userId to the endpoint

I am currently able to test the endpoint that returns all users however when I try to write a test to return specific user data by attaching the user's id to the route I just end up testing the route returning all users.

```
describe('User profile route', () => {

  let token = '';
  let userId = '';
  let userId1 = '';
  useInTest();

  it('should return a specific user details', (done) => {
    signUp(mockData.signUpData).expect(201)
      .end(() => {});
    signUp(mockData.signUpData1).expect(201)
      .end(() => {});
    login(mockData.loginData)
      .expect(200)
      .end((err, res) => {
        token = res.body.accessToken;
        userId = res.body.user._id;
      });

    agent.get(`/api/users/${userId1}`).set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
      .expect(200)
      .end((err, res) => {
        console.log(res.body);
        res.body.should.have.length(1);
        done();
      })
  });
}
```

I expect that test to pass but unfortunately, it doesn't simply it keeps hitting the this `api/users` instead of hitting this `api/users/:id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not a supertest issue. How about you make test asynchronous because by the time your test makes a request the userId could be undefined since it is set after login. Try updating you code like this(add words in asterisks):

```
it('should return a specific user details', **async**(done) => {
signUp(mockData.signUpData).expect(201)
  .end(() => {});
signUp(mockData.signUpData1).expect(201)
  .end(() => {});
**await** login(mockData.loginData)
  .expect(200)
  .**then**((err, res) => {
    token = res.body.accessToken;
    userId = res.body.user._id;
  });

agent.get(`/api/users/${userId1}`).set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
  .expect(200)
  .end((err, res) => {
    console.log(res.body);
    res.body.should.have.length(1);
    done();
  })
```

});

Comment: This has actually helped me to hit the endpoint @Herman but now I seem to be getting another problem because of using the async I need to get reed of the done() function and when I do I get some other error. Let me try and see how I can go about this but feel free to share an idea on what I can do about it

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to get the issue solved completely

```js
describe('User profile route', () => {

  let token = '';
  let userId = '';
  let userId1 = '';
  useInTest();
  beforeEach( async () => {
    signUp(mockData.signUpData).end(() => {});
    signUp(mockData.signUpData1).end(() => {});
    await login(mockData.loginData)
      .then((res) => {
        token = res.body.accessToken;
        userId = res.body.user._id;
      });
    await login(mockData.loginData1)
      .then((res) => {
        userId1 = res.body.user._id;
      });
  });

  it('should return user profile for the currently logged in user', (done) => {
    agent.get('/api/users/' + userId).set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
      .end((err, res) => {
        res.body.should.have.property('name', 'Arnold');
        done();
      });
  });
}
```